# How to create custom tree structure in Angular with reactive form?

Tags: angular, tree

From API response need to create the custom tree. Each node has one dropdown which options are 'No' & 'Yes'. All nodes has one button at end of the each node. If I select the first root node value as 'Yes' and then click that button, bottom of all other node dropdown should changed to 'Yes' and vice versa for 'No'. The table headers are below.

**Area**             **Access**            **Apply To All**
UK                     Yes/No                   downarrow_icon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuqy3.png)

My requirement is get the changed node's 'nodeName' as an array. Example if I changed the value of UK as 'Yes' and apply to all means my array is `selectedArea: ['Z00', 'R11', 'AFT']`

My component.html:

```
<mat-tree
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  [treeControl]="treeControl"
  class="example-tree"
>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
    {{node.nodeDesc}} <span style="padding-left: 20px"></span>
    <select>
      <option value="No">No</option>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    </select>
    <mat-icon>cloud_download</mat-icon>
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild">
    <div class="mat-tree-node">
      <button
        mat-icon-button
        matTreeNodeToggle
        [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name"
      >
        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
          {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
        </mat-icon>
      </button>
      {{node.nodeDesc}}
      <select>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      </select>
      <mat-icon>cloud_download</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div
      [class.example-tree-invisible]="!treeControl.isExpanded(node)"
      role="group"
    >
      <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
    </div>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

My component.ts:

```
import { NestedTreeControl } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTreeNestedDataSource, MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


const TREE_DATA = [
  {
    nodeId: null,
    nodeName: 'Z00',
    nodeDesc: 'UK',
    division: 'SD',
    nodeParent: null,
    nodeLevel: '0',
    accessLevel: 'No',
    children: [
      {
        nodeId: null,
        nodeName: 'R11',
        nodeDesc: 'Ireland',
        division: 'SD',
        nodeParent: 'Z00',
        nodeLevel: '1',
        accessLevel: 'No',
        children: [
          {
            nodeId: null,
            nodeName: 'G29',
            nodeDesc: 'Northern Ireland',
            division: 'SD',
            nodeParent: 'R11',
            nodeLevel: '2',
            accessLevel: 'No',
            children: [
              {
                nodeId: null,
                nodeName: 'AFT',
                nodeDesc: 'Aelbast',
                division: 'SD',
                nodeParent: 'G29',
                nodeLevel: '3',
                accessLevel: 'No',
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];


@Component({
  selector: 'tree-nested-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-nested-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-nested-overview-example.css'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTreeModule, MatButtonModule, MatIconModule],
})
export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  treeControl = new NestedTreeControl<any>((node) => node.children);
  dataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<any>();

  constructor() {
    this.dataSource.data = TREE_DATA;
  }

  hasChild = (_: number, node: any) =>
    !!node.children && node.children.length > 0;
}
```